# Notification on database insertion in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

my web application has more than one user with unique usercode. As soon as a new record is inserted into the database with some usercode, i want to show a popup only to that user in his browser window.

for example
    insert into mytable(usercode) values(1431) 
is inserted into my databasetable.
if user with usercode 1431,1435 are loggedin. i want to show the notification only to the user with usercode=1431

Comment: "my web application has more than one user with unique usercode" - say what? if more than user user has the same code, how is it unique?

Comment: When you ask a question, and someone answers, you mark an answer as correct so that others can find your question useful. You've accepted 0 answers to all 7 of your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the following links below and pick the one suits you best!

Using SqlNotificationRequest to Subscribe to Query Notifications
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190270.aspx

Using SqlDependency to Subscribe to Query Notifications
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179575.aspx

Cheers,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

To notify the client, i.e. the browser, I think your only option is for JavaScript on the client that polls the server using an Ajax request.  Then you can query the DB in each Ajax call and check if new records for the user have been added.  Alternatively you can use on eof the methods linked to by @StefanE, and store change notifications.  You will still have to poll from the client though.